# How make text area resizable in IE11 by mouse?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Text Area is resizeable in firefox and chrome but in IE11 it is not resizeable through mouse in my ruby on rails application.

```
=text_area_tag("resize", data, {:style=>'width: 227px;background: #eae9e7', :rows => 3, :readonly => true}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try [jQueryUI's Resizable](http://jqueryui.com/resizable/#textarea) for resizing textareas.

You need to include jQuery UI library for this:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

and call the `resizable` method on your textarea:

```
$("#text-area-id").resizable({ });
```

Comment: @dimakura - Thanks It's not exactly works for me but really helpful and I have resolved my issue.